# XAML for MS Calendar app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Is it possible to view the XAML for the MS Calendar app on Windows Phone 8? I wondered if the source was perhaps included since you can use the app on the WP8 emulator, unlikely I guess.

I'd love to know how they're dealing with the scrolling, it works flawlessly.

I'm having trouble with a ScrollViewer where when the keyboard is visible you can't scroll the full height of the content, but this doesn't happen in the Calendar app.

There's quite a lot of posts online about this issue but can't find a solution. I have already posted a question about this but unfortunately didn't receive any pointers.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The source for the apps that come with the OS, such as calendar, messaging, email, calculator, etc. is not available.

In fact, it's not even written in XAML. So even if it was available it wouldn't help you.
The native apps are written with a different UI technology that is not available to third parties.

Comment: Is it really using different UI technology? I would like to know more about it if you have any sources :)

Comment: @ToniPetrina I believe it's called SplashUI. Rumour has it that it is what was originally used to build the UI on the Zune devices. It was used for the native apps because they were written while the Silvelight SDK was also being written. There is no public documentation on this and no way to use it.